# How to upload Unity3d Android build on google play? how to use the license key?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I have created a game in unity3d and made an android build. But when I wanted to upload it on google play store, I got the liscence key and this message,
Does anybody know where I can put that licence key? When you look into Developer console there is Licence key

"Base64-encoded RSA public key to include in your binary. Please remove any spaces."

How to use this key?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Playersettings in the Build Window

1. Locate the Publishing Settings under PlayerSettings
2. Create a new keystore by selecting a keystore name and password (confirm the password)
3. Select "Create a new key" under Key Alias
4. A new window opens; enter the necessary information.
5. Select the newly created key.
6. Build ( Run); your app is now signed.

source:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/android-signing.62137/

Answer (score 0):

Just Sign Your Application From Build Setting->Player Setting ->publishing Settings Create a new Keystore and keep it to yourself.